# Subtraction in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two select queries like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(WARD_id) 
FROM IP_Admission 
WHERE (Status = 'V' OR Status = 'D') AND WARD_ID = 1

SELECT BED_STRENGTH 
FROM Ward_Master 
WHERE Ward_ID = 1
```

Output of the query is

```
   2
   6
```

Now I need answer **4**. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(i.ward_id) - w.bed_strength as Diff from 
ip_admission i join ward_master  w on w.ward_id=i.ward_id
where (status='V' or status='D') and i.ward_id=1
group by w.bed_strength
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'ward_master.Bed_Strength' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: if you are using more columns in your query you need to group by all the columns that has not used aggregate function

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
declare @a int
declare @b int

SELECT @a = COUNT(WARD_id) FROM IP_Admission WHERE (Status='V' OR Status='D') AND WARD_ID=1

SELECT @b = BED_STRENGTH FROM Ward_Master WHERE Ward_ID=1

select @b - @a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This for all ward ID's

```
SELECT M.Ward_ID,BED_STRENGTH -COUNT(WARD_id)  
FROM IP_Admission A  
     JOIN  Ward_Master M ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID 
WHERE (A.Status='V' OR A.Status='D') 
GROUP BY M.Ward_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are pulled these values from two different tables, the best way to do this will to be to join the table on ward id.

```
SELECT wm.BED_STRENGTH - COUNT(ip.WARD_id) 
FROM Ward_Master wm inner join IP_Admission ip
         On wm.ward_id = ip.ward_id
WHERE (ip.Status='V' OR ip.Status='D')
Group by wm.BED_STRENGTH
```

This should work, but it might not depending on the schema. The advantage with this method is that it will find the value for all ward ids.

The simplest solution is:

```
SELECT (subquery1) - (subquery2)
```

This will only show the value for the ward id that you specify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join like this.  Please let me know if this doesn't work.

```
create table #Tmp1
(
    Ward_Id INT,
    Status Char(1)
)

create table #tmp2
(
    Ward_Id INT,
    BED_STRENGTH INT
)

INSERT INTO #Tmp1 VALUES (1,'V'),(1,'D')

INSERT INTO #tmp2 VALUES (1,6)

SELECT COUNT(WARD_id) 
FROM #Tmp1 
WHERE (Status='V' OR Status='D') AND WARD_ID=1

SELECT BED_STRENGTH FROM #Tmp2 WHERE Ward_ID=1

SELECT #tmp2.BED_STRENGTH -  COUNT(#tmp1.WARD_id) 
FROM #Tmp1 
INNER JOIN #tmp2 ON #tmp2.Ward_Id = #tmp1.Ward_Id 
WHERE (Status='V' OR Status='D') AND #tmp1.WARD_ID=1
GROUP BY #tmp2.BED_STRENGTH

DROP TABLE #Tmp1 

DROP TABLE #Tmp2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i solved my query as

```
   SELECT M.Bed_Strength - COUNT(A.WARD_id)  as diff
  FROM IP_Admission A  
JOIN  Ward_Master M ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID 
 WHERE (A.Status='V' OR A.Status='D') and M.Ward_ID=1 group by M.Bed_Strength;
```

Comment: that's the answer i have posted.

Comment: My answer was also the same.  I have elaborated for better understanding.